# Windows task scheduler created programmatically in C# not running automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, scheduler

I have created windows task scheduler programmatically in c#. Task is created successfully and is scheduled to run correctly. At scheduled time, it says task is running but without any result and next schedule time is updated.

But last run time and last run result does not update.

**Last run result is: The task has not yet run.(0x41303)**

But when run manually from task scheduler it executes successfully but not automatically.

Below code that i used to create task

```
var ts = new TaskService();
var td = ts.NewTask();
td.RegistrationInfo.Author = "My company";
td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Runs test application";
var trigger = new WeeklyTrigger { StartBoundary = startDate, DaysOfWeek = daysOfWeek, Enabled = enabled };
trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(((minutes == 0) ? 60 : minutes) * 60);
td.Triggers.Add(trigger);
var action = new ExecAction(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, null, null);
if (filePath != string.Empty && File.Exists(filePath))
{
    action = new ExecAction(filePath);
}
action.Arguments = "AutoRun";
td.Actions.Add(action);
ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(TaskName, td);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You would be better of creating the piece of task in C# and let the windows task scheduler take care of scheduling part. Is there a particular reason why you did not take this approach ?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code that creates the scheduled task?

Comment: @LarsKristensen - Added code for reference.

Comment: can you please check my updated answer @Ronak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, for running any task in scheduler, laptop charger must be plugged in else scheduler does not execute the task.

This is not the case with windows server or desktop systems.

Not sure about this behavior but this is what i figured it out.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, It help me today! By Disabling ```Conditions -> Start the task only if the computer is on AC power``` it started working on laptops.

Answer (score 1):

Check the execution privileges first.
Then check the task manager if the process is really running when it seems 'running'. If yes, try to use some try-catch blocks and create event logs as exceptions.

I think when you run manually from task scheduler, its executed by a user that belongs to task scheduler (maybe administrator). But at scheduled time, application trying to be executed as a user that won't have enough privileges to do some stuff in your code.

### UPDATE

1. Set Start in (optional) value to target file location. Without it,
   the task scheduler runs in system32 folder but like i said before,
   target application wouldn't have privileges to run in system32.
2. Try to change the version of the console application to 32 bit.

   i.e. Right click  Goto  -> Properties -> Build ->  Platform Target 
   = x86.

Comment: No, by changing app to 32 bit it is not working. I think it is due to privileges but not confirmed. How can i give myself access so that with my user task can be executed automatically. Any idea?

Comment: Try to enable "Run with highest privileges" manually and let schedule time to execute it. If it works, then you can update your code with it. If it doesn't works, i think its about "start in" location.

Comment: Just tried with Run with highest privileges...but no luck. Also added .exe path to start in location but again no luck.

Comment: do you have the source code of target executable files? if yes, try using event logger to debug what's going on step by step.

Comment: By using NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM it was working till now. But suddenly it stopped executing automatically again. Is there any way we can troubleshoot this issue. This is driving me crazy now.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the executable crashing with "Application Error". You can't see any error in Task scheduler. It will just show last run result as "The task has not yet run.(0x41303)"

TO get the error please check Event Viewer

EventViewer -> Windows Logs ->  Aplication

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to @Ronak answer. If you are trying this in laptop, ensure `Conditions -> Start the task only if the computer is on AC power`  is disabled.